# How can I put an EXPANDABLE / DRILLDOWNABLE shortcut like "This PC" from the Desktop toolbar into another shortcut

Tags: windows, windows-10

Sorry for the convoluted title, I'll try to explain...

Right click taskbar, Toolbars, select the Desktop toolbar to display it.

Now, when you open that toolbar and then hover over "This PC", a sub-menu flies out that shows lots of other icons including hard drives, and you can continue this navigation style drilling down to a specific deeply nested sub-folder and right click to open.

This is great, I find this very useful, but I don't want to display this entire toolbar to get access to just that shortcut, I'd like to put it onto one of my other shortcut folders, but I can't figure out how to do that while retaining the drill-down capability.

(Not sure if this is relevant, but most of the other shortcuts on that toolbar also support this flyout sub-menu capability.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "close enough" solution is to make a symbolic link to each drive; unless shortcuts, symbolic links support this same drill down behavior.